# Oracle empty string/NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have to write an SQL SELECT statement which is valid for MS SQL Server and Oracle. I have to work with old customer databases, so I cannot change anything in the db design...

Problem is that the table has a nullable column 'project' which is a varchar that is in some cases filled with an empty string - which is translated by oracle to NULL.
So how do I select all columns that have an NON empty 'project'?

```
WHERE project IS NOT NULL                   works for oracle
WHERE project <> ''                         works for MS
WHERE project IS NOT NULL AND project <> '' works for MS, but not for Oracle
```

Thanks,
Marko

Comment: It's like writing a code statement that is valid in both Java and C++ :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the condition `'' = ''` will be true only in SQL-Server (it's equivalent to `'' IS NOT NULL`) and the condition `'' IS NULL` will be true only in Oracle, you can use this:

```
WHERE ( project > '' AND '' = '')              -- for SQL-Server
   OR ( project IS NOT NULL AND '' IS NULL)    -- for Oracle
```

Note that if you have values that are only spaces, they will be treated differently between SQL-Server and Oracle. Test **[SQL-Fiddle-1 (Oracle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7fd97/1)** and **[SQL-Fiddle-2 (SQL-Server)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fd97/2)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NULLIF()`, which is available in both [SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) and [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions107.htm#SQLRF00681) (it's part of the ANSI standard).

```
select *
  from table
 where nullif(project, '') is not null
```

It works because Oracle evaluates the empty string to NULL. It's worth noting that Oracle does not evaluate `NULLIF()` if the first expression is NULL, but it does work this way round.

Answer (score -2):

facts:

- Oracle translate empty to NULL
- SQL Server does not translate.

So if you have a Oracle and SQL Server database with same content, the result is the same, something you really want

```
where (project is not null OR project <> '')
```

Comment: This will include the empty strings in SQL-Server.

Comment: In oracle the empty string is translate to NULL so with the results form oracle and sql are the same with this statement

Comment: [It returns an incorrect result in SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/146c9/1)